# How to deserialize Json elements in which the having same elements collection in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have a collection of elements in json and inside it having the same collection of elements same as , nested elements collection so how to deserialize in c#

I already tried this .
I created a C# class of elements with properties also property of collection of same class

```
//C# Code
class pages
{
    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<elements> elements { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
class elements
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }

    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<choices> choices { get; set; }

    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<elements> element { get; set; }
}

//My Json
{
"pages": [
 {
  "name": "page1",
  "elements": [
  {
 "type": "panel",
 "name": "Q1",
 "elements": [
  {
   "type": "text",
   "name": "Q2",
   "title": "What is your age ?"
  },
  {
   "type": "radiogroup",
   "name": "QHidden",
   "choices": [
    {
     "value": "1",
     "text": "<18"
    },
    {
     "value": "2",
     "text": "18-30"
    },
    {
     "value": "3",
     "text": "30-50"
    },
    {
     "value": "4",
     "text": ">50"
     }
     ]
     }
    ]
    }
   ]
  }
  ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a separate class of elements with same properties

```
   class elements
   {
     public string type { get; set; }
     public string name { get; set; }
     public string title { get; set; }

     public System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<choices> choices { get; set; }

     public System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<elements2> element { get; set; 
     }
   }

   class elements2
   {
     public string type { get; set; }
     public string name { get; set; }
     public string title { get; set; }

     public System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<choices> choices { get; set; }
   }
```

This worked for me